# Improve Printing First and Last Name of Sorted Directory

Tags: c, sorting, directory

I am beginner at C and learning as I progress. I have adopted and modified a program to print the names of the files in the directory in sorted order.
I only would like to print the First and Last file in the sorted order.
(eg: c.txt, z.docx, f.jpg, a.docx: Output will be a.docx and z.docx)

Directory Size: Almost 2,000,000 Files 
File Size: Each size is at most 2MB

Hurdles 
The first name prints as "." and the second name is ".." 
Sorting is done via uppercase, how to switch to lowercase

It would also be great to know, if there is a simpler or better way of executing the below code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int
main(void)
{
    struct dirent **namelist;
    int n;
    int i = 0;

    n = scandir(".", &namelist, NULL, alphasort);
    if (n < 0)
    {
        perror("scandir");
    }
    else
    {
        while (i<n)
        {
            if (i == 0) // First Name
            {
                printf("%s\n", (namelist[i])->d_name);
            }
            if (i == n-1) // Last Name
            {
                printf("%s\n", (namelist[i])->d_name);
            }
            free(namelist[n]);
            i++;
        }
        free(namelist);

    }
}
```

Comment: You could print the first and last before the `while()` loop, and simplify the loop to just `free()` memory. You should also check if there is more than 1 file before printing the last entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe if you remove the while part and print just the third (to disconsider . and ..) and last entrance:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int
main(void)
{
    struct dirent **namelist;
    int n;
    int i = 0;

    n = scandir(".", &namelist, NULL, alphasort);
    if (n < 0)
    {
        perror("scandir");
    }
    else
    {

        printf("%s\n", (namelist[2])->d_name);
        printf("%s\n", (namelist[n-1])->d_name);

        while(i<n)
            free(namelist[i++]);
        free(namelist);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And don't forget the `return 0`; As you specified that you should return a `int` in your main. Now you can print your stuff in constant time, but memory still need Θ(n) to be deallocated.
If you also want to disconsider hidden files (starting with '.') you should add a filter function as:

```
int filter(const struct dirent *entry) {
    return entry->d_name[0] != '.';
}
```

and add it to `scandir` arguments

```
scandir(".", &namelist, filter, alphasort);
```

and then you should alter first print index, because '.' and '..' will be treat by filter.

```
printf("%s\n", (namelist[0])->d_name);
```

Comment: How can I make sure the Lowercase Items are first and the Uppercase the second. Eg (Aa.txt and aa.txt; output should be aa.txt, Aa.txt. It should not be Aa.txt, aa.txt which is currently happening)